# Evalutate this integral $I = \int_0^{\infty} dx J_1(x) \frac{x^2 - \sin(x^2)}{x^4}$

Tags: integration

I want to calcuate the integral
$$I = \int_0^{\infty} dx J_1(x) \frac{x^2 - \sin(x^2)}{x^4}$$
where $J_1(x)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind.
The integrand is well-behaved for $x \rightarrow 0$; and for $x \rightarrow \infty$, it decays like $1/x^2$ plus oscillation behavior of the Bessel function.
We can plot it for $x \in (0,10)$, which is shown below:

[image]

So it looks like this integration is at least well-defined.
I tried to convert it into a contour integral and use the residue theorem trick. However, sooner I realize that I have difficulty finding a suitable complex integration which is related to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Using only a **Mathematica 13.1** I have:

$$ \int_0^{\infty } \frac{J_1(x) \left(x^2-\sin \left(x^2\right)\right)}{x^4} \, dx=\\\frac{\pi }{64}-\frac{1}{8} \cos
   \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{\text{Ci}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{4}+\frac{1}{2} \sin
   \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{\text{Si}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{32}\approx 0.250056$$

Where:$\text{Ci}(x)$ and $\text{Si}(x)$ is CosineIntegral and SineIntegral.

Comment: WOW! How did you manage to let Mathematica give an exact solution? I tried with 13.0 version but it returns nothing. I tried to do the numerical integration instead, I got the number 0.250056, which I thought was 1/4 then. Based on this answer, the integral isn't as simple as I thought. Thanks!

Comment: Try:`FullSimplify[
 InverseMellinTransform[
   Apart[Integrate[
      MellinTransform[BesselJ[1, a x]*(x^2 - Sin[x^2])/x^4, a, s], {x,
        0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> s > -1], s][[1]], s, a] /. 
  a -> 1]`